# ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/branch (no new changes)

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit, git-push, git-remote

I have merged a branch and tried to push the changes into Gerrit,

```
git checkout dev
git merge feature
```

After merging my status shows like,

```
$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 35 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then I tried to push

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/dev
```

Getting below error,

```
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/dev (no new changes)
```

Couple of SO answers ([answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23808032/1084174), [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51731569/1084174), [answer3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946653/gerrit-after-add-commit-to-local-git-repo-i-receive-remote-rejected-no-cha)) suggested to amend before push but I have many CLs which got merged.
**Now how can I deal with this situation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to push changes for review (to `refs/for/foo`), always use `git merge --no-ff` to create a merge commit. The merge commit will be reviewed, and once it's submitted, the merged branch will be introduced to the target branch.

Without a merge commit, the merged commits have already been reviewed before on the merged branch in the perspective of Gerrit. That's why Gerrit responds with `no new changes` as they are not new to Gerrit.

To solve the current issue, you could try:

```
git reset origin/dev --hard
git merge feature --no-ff

# if your repository requires ChangeID, use "git commit --amend" to invoke the hook to generate ChangeID.
git commit --amend

git push origin HEAD:refs/for/dev
```